# Express 4 - How to properly serve routes from other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My simple Express 4 app is giving me heartache. Heres the setup:

routes/profile.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
  res.send('you are looking at a profile');
});

module.exports = router;
```

./router.js

```
module.exports.routes = function(app) {
  var index = require('./routes/index');
  var profile = require('./routes/profile')

  app.use('/', index);
  app.use('/profile', profile);
};
```

and in ./app.js

```
...
var registerRoutes = require('./router');
...
registerRoutes(app);
```

Now this works fine for when I go to `localhost:3000` and it displays the standard Express stuff.

But when I go to `/profile` it gives a 404 error.

However, in profile.js, if I change `router.get('/profile'...` to `router.get('/'...` it works fine.

Why? And is this ok? My gut tells me no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths defined in routing modules are relative to the path that got them there. When you try to access the `/profile`  endpoint, express is finding the module you created, and then looking for a `'/'` endpoint within that module. It isn't finding one since your handler is mapped to `'/profile'`, so it continues down the chain in app.js until it hits your 404 handler.

**TL;DR:** The changes you made that were working are how routing works in express. Fix the endpoint inside of your module to `'/'`, or try navigating to `/profile/profile`.

Comment: Yeah, I literally just figured that out myself and was in the process of answering my own question. You however said it better and deserve the respect. Winning